# Selective access to a SSL web application

Tags: iis-7, ssl-certificate, certificate, certificate-authority

I have a web application powered by IIS7 secured with SSL certificate over web. I want to restrict the access of my site to selected clients. I can't restrict IP based or firewall based access control.
**Requirement:** Only the client PCs with client side certificate (we install on their system) may access our website.
**Question:** Which client-side certificate i require to implement the above scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you would generate the certificates from your CA and those certificates would be associated with the user accounts in AD. Make sure you add the Client Certificate Mapping Authentication role. There are multiple ways you can map certificates to accounts. You will need to choose which method is best for your environment. As an example you can have many certificates map to an account, one certificate map to one account, or you can use Active Directory Mapping.

https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/authentication/clientcertificatemappingauthentication

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732996%28v=ws.10%29.aspx